# bug reporting webapp for customers

Tags: report

I need a recommendation on some solid bug reporting/tracking webapp(preferably free and in PHP) that I can host in house to provide customers with a bug reporting/feature request tool.  any suggestions?

I've had experience with trac.  Bugzilla looks good, anyone had experience with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redmine](http://redmine.org) (open source, written in Ruby).

Answer (score 0):

This probably belongs on SuperUser, but I'd suggest [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) if you want something free and self hosted.